# How to identify offending full trust asp.net code in a medium trust environment

Tags: c#, asp.net

We are deploying our MVC3 C# web application to a new hosting environment. The environment we came from allowed full trust applications levels. The new hosting environment only allows medium trust, thus our application is now throwing security errors for calls requiring full trust. We have been reviewing our code trying to find the offending calls so we can work around the trust issues but have been unsuccessful in finding the specific lines of code. Below is the exception we are getting which is quite vague to the origin of the call:

**Security Exception**
**Description:** The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

**Exception Details:** System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

**Source Error:**
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web
request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,      
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark&  
stackMark,      
Boolean isPermSet) +0
System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap,
StackCrawlMark&  
stackMark) +31
System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, 
Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options,
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath,
Boolean checkHost) +654
System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare
share) +65
System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.StaticOpenStreamForRead(String  
streamName) +85
System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.
IInternalCon    figHost.OpenStreamForRead(String streamName, Boolean assertPermissions)    
+116
System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigHost.System.Configuration.Internal.
IInternalCon figHost.OpenStreamForRead(String streamName) +10
System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.OpenStreamForRead(String streamName)
+11
System.Configuration.UpdateConfigHost.OpenStreamForRead(String streamName) +38
System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile() +319
```

We were wondering if anyone can give us some insight on one how to track down this security level error. Is there any type of application or plugin that can assist us in determining the location of the issue? Second can anyone shed light on when these exceptions are thrown? Does the offending code have to be called to throw the exception or does this error occur when the page is being compiled on the web server?

Comment: Appears to be an error reading a file. Does the account associated with the application pool have permissions set on the file you are reading? The other place this commonly happens is attempting to read sections from Web.config using WebConfigurationManager. Can't do it in Medium Trust. Workaround for that would be opening the config in an XML document and reading it that way.

Comment: @Sam  I commented all that code out and removed the using references
still get that error. I believe the issue is in a 3rd party dll, like mysql connector, SubSonic ORM but don't now how to track an issue like that down?

Comment: The easiest way to track it down is going to be to load the site up in your development environment. Add <trust level="Medium" /> to the <system.web> section of your web.config file, then run in debug mode. It should show you where the error is being thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! We tried this it does produce the same errors as on the server, but the exception never shows up in Visual Studio. We checked the console, and the call stack with no success. It almost seems like it is blowing up during compile time. Any other suggestions? We also tried creating a stock mvc project and adding the dll's we use. We included using statements and could not reproduce the exception. A few days now with no success!

Comment: Sorry Pyraego, no more ideas on this one.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Still no luck :(

Comment: Try ELMAH, that might help.